# How to include the external html file into html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

I have url contain html.

http://s3test.sirahu.net/12518%3A11679%3A581?&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJEI7M6ZBESTUUDIA&Expires=1357973634&Signature=2G7M2uQJ%2Ba9LJUcGgEbxcItsBKQ%3D

I need to include and display this CDN HTML content in my web page.
  I have tried with ajax but I got cross domain issues and I have also tried with iframe also but url will download not display in an iframe.

Comment: What did you try? How did you try `iframe`?

Comment: This URL is a download link. You have to modify it first. Is it your domain? Do you have access rights to this content?

Comment: please check this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/FV8MK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server responds with `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="17893_content.html"` (meaning "Download this, don't display it") and claims that the file is `binary/octet-stream` not `text/html`.

If you want a browser to render it, then the server must claim that it is HTML and not say that it should be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use postMessage method for crossdomain requests (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried it will download in new window. i need to show this html content in same page